# Is "due to be published" correct?

Tags: prepositions

An excerpt from [The Economist](https://www.economist.com/britain/2021/02/13/boris-johnsons-nhs-prescription-more-control-less-competition):

> A white paper, **due to be published as the Economist went to press but leaked beforehand**, sets out plans for the first major NHS legislation in a decade.

I believe ["due to"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/due%20to) is a preposition, so how does "be published" follow it? Shouldn't it be "being published"?

---

Just to make it clear, I am not asking the meaning of the sentence, but rather the grammatical construction.

Comment: This is a different sense of _due to_. The paper was not scheduled to be published until after that issue of _The Economist_, but the journalists knew what was going to be in it because the information had been 'leaked'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were the causal sense of "due to", you'd be right.

However, there's another sense of "due" that means "scheduled". Try replacing the word and it makes sense:

> A white paper, scheduled to be published...

This sense probably grows out of the sense "owed", which is the meaning the word originally had in French: "Ten dollars are due to the plaintiff." From there, at least two metaphorical senses developed. One is the causal usage, which developed that way in French as well: a result is "owing to, due to" a cause.

The other is a little more subtle. Here's a set of examples that show the meaning balancing between "owed" and "scheduled" till the line blurs.

> When is the assignment due? (owed, i.e. obligated to be given to the teacher)

> It's due on the 27th.

> The 27th is the due date. Don't miss the deadline.

> Your library book is overdue! You had to return it yesterday.

> A raise and some time off are overdue.

> You're due for a raise!

> When is it due to be published?